# why in batch script do not working the "do set" function?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following problem in batch scripting.

I have this code lines

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /b /s a2lfiles_merger*.txt') do set merger_list=%%d
echo %merger_list%
```

and the result is `Echo is OFF`

Then i tried this code

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /b /s a2lfiles_merger*.txt') do echo %%d
```

The result is `C:\Users\user\Desktop\Build\Input\JOB_1\a2lfiles_merger.txt`

So, the question is why i cannot set a variable with the path? I need to use it in the next steps and now i am stuck in this situation. Can anyone find a solution ? Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Your first sample is in a code block / parenthesis.  The `set` works but the percent expansion in the echo line fails. In this case you need to use delayed expansion

Comment: @jeb, the first line is _not_ a block as there are no parentheses; if no file `a2lfiles_merger*.txt` can be found, `echo` results in `Echo is off.`; if at least one file is found, the last one is displayed; so I guess it is a path issue (where is the code called from?)...

Comment: @jeb Thank you, it's working. Could you explain the diffirent between `! & %`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

revised code:

```
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /b /s a2lfiles_merger*.txt') do (
set merger_list=%%d
    echo !merger_list!
)
```

note the setlocal command and the parenthesis enclosing the commands to be executed in the for-loop. that's how for loops work.

hope that helped!

Comment: You'll need to expand the variable like this: `echo !merger_list!`!!

Comment: @aschipfl  %merger_list% needs to be !merger_list! in this case

Comment: Should have tested it myself. Thanks guys!