# Why a Batch script is not working properly when i moved it on an other PC?

Tags: windows, batch-file

According to my previous question i found a solution for my problem.[prev Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721634/why-in-batch-script-do-not-working-the-do-set-function/31722348#31722348)

I have written my script but i moved it to my server and i was surprised because the script does not working anymore. I made a new one only for testing and the solution from the previous question is not anymore workable!

Here is my test script

```
@echo off
TITLE MyBatch
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "merger_list=C:\"
set "source=C:\ASAP2-Build\Input"
set "target=C:\ASAP2-Build\Output"

:loop
Rem this "for" loop executed for all folders in source path. /ad -> folder. /o:d -> sorted by date and time. /s -> include all subfolders. /b -> bare format
 for /f %%i in ('dir %source% /ad /o:d /s /b') do (
        rem command.merging is an empty file which works as a command. We use it to triger the merging function.
        if exist %%i\command.merging (
            rem a2lfiles_merger is a text file with a list, this list includes all the slave a2l files into a list to merging.
           if exist %%i\a2lfiles_merger*.txt (
             rem this loop have to find the complete name of the a2lfiles_merger. Will be f.ex. a2lfiles_merger2.txt 
                for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /b /s   a2lfiles_merger*.txt') do ( 
                set merger_list=%%d
                echo !merger_list!
                )
            
            )
        )
        
    )
echo Folder is empty or does not exist
timeout /t 5
goto loop
```

The problem occurs when i call this line

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /b /s a2lfiles_merger*.txt') do ( 
                set merger_list=%%d
                echo !merger_list!
                )
```

The screen prints the message `Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.` The translation is `The system cannot find the file.`

I have to explain why i need this code, in every folder there is always a txt file with an unknown name but always in form `a2lfiles_merger*.txt`. Some folders have the file `a2lfiles_merger2.txt` and others `a2lfiles_merger3.txt` etc.

So it is so dificult to me to understand why this script runs at my computer and not at my server. The server has also windows 7.
Have someone a suggestion ?

Comment: @jeb I am not sure if i understand you, but i try to check if the txt file exist, if not i have an error. If the list exist, i try to retrieve the whole of the name.
When i have the name i call the program but in this test script i  do nothing more.

Comment: @jeb `if exist` **does** accept wildcards. However, I'd use (note no `/s` switch bu full path instead) `for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /ad /b  "%%i\a2lfiles_merger*.txt"') do (` followed by `set "merger_list=%%i\%%d"` line and then `echo !merger_list!)` line...

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, `if exist` CAN use wildcards, but even then you should enclose your filenames in quotes, like `if exist "%%i\a2lfiles*" (` to avoid confusion with spaces. You should add `ECHO` commands at many lines to get the real problem

Comment: ...or remove `@echo off` and review every echoed line...

Comment: this is th e final version which working for me!! Thank you
`if exist "%%i\a2lfiles_merger*" (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /b "%%i\a2lfiles_merger*.txt" ') do (set merger_list=%%i\%%d )`

Comment: Oh yes, I  passed over wrong `/AD` switch contradicting the `*.txt` file attribute...

Answer (score 0):

Right there at the beginning - you have quotes in the wrong place:

set "merger_list=C:\"

Shouldn't that be:

set merger_list="C:\"

That's a bad start ;)

Comment: Look the second answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552812/declaring-and-using-a-variable-in-dos-windows-batch-file-bat
I think you dont have right!